# C#/Mono Console.In.ReadToEnd() stopping process

Tags: c#, linux, mono, console

If I have the following code:

```
namespace foo {
 public class FooClass {
  public static void Main (string[] argsRaw) {
   Console.WriteLine(Console.In.ReadToEnd());
  }
 }
}
```

And I run it, process will stop once the end of the stream is reached.

Output:

```
(Text of my input stream)
[1]+  Stopped                 bin/Debug/foo.exe
```

How do I get my program to behave more like grep, which does not stop after hitting EOF?

Comment: Logan: On Linux it would probably be Ctrl+D.

Comment: @Gabe right. but on Linux Ctrl+Z generally suspends the process. I'm wondering if he's a Window's transplant getting tripped up.

Comment: I'm not hitting a key, actually.  I'm dumping a file in as the input... $ ./foo.exe < myjunk.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You need to make sure that Main's return type is an int.

```
namespace foo {
    public class FooClass {
        public static int Main (string[] argsRaw) {
            Console.WriteLine(Console.In.ReadToEnd());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Works.